# Flink marks source late arriving events

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We're building a Flink app that consumes events from different Kafka topics. This app uses the bounded out of order watermark strategy on the source. During normal execution everything works as expected and we do not get any late arriving data (based on watermarks), but on checkpoints/ savepoints restores we're getting late arriving events, no matter how much we increase the out of order bound. Did anyone ever encounter this situation?

Comment: You're using event time (NOT process time) everywhere, and your watermark strategy is based on event times extracted from records, yes?

Comment: Yes, I'm using event time everywhere. What is confusing is that I'm getting different behaviour (non deterministic) during normal execution and on recovery over the same period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Watermarks are not checkpointed, so after recovery, the watermarks have to be re-established based on the events processed after the checkpoint. If one or more sources are more-or-less idle at that point in time, this could explain why the behavior is so different compared to the situation before the restart.

Comment: Thanks I get this point, but sometimes I'm restoring a checkpoint of say 24 hours ago, and start getting out-of-order events after a few hours are already processed, e.g., out-of-orders events within the past 16 hours.

Comment: I think the problem is the following though not sure how to confirm it. I'm consuming from two Kafka topics each with 3k events per seconds. On recovery, Flink is consuming Kafka events very fast, I'm guessing that within a watermark generation interval (200ms) Flink is consuming events with timestamp difference of more than my out of order bound (30s), e.g., events from time t to time t + 40s, watermark generation kicks in setting watermark to t+40s, hence the batch of events from time t to time t+30s are considered late. Do you think this is plausible?

Comment: That will only happen if you have somehow avoided using per-partition watermarking. How is your watermarking set up?

Comment: I'm setting the following watermark on the Flink KafkaSource. My single Kafka source is consuming from 2 different topics (1 topic-4 partitions, another topic-6 partitions). I thought setting WS on source is enough to use per-partition wm

final KafkaSource<XXX> kafkaSource = ...
WatermarkStrategy<XXX> watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
watermarkStrategy = watermarkStrategy.withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getEventTimestampUTC());
this.env.fromSource(kafkaSource, watermarkStrategy, "some_name")
                ...

Comment: I think the scenario I described can still happen when using using per-partition watermarking. If within one watermark interval, a Kafka consumer reads events from all partitions, and from EACH partition reads events with timestamps ranging from time_t to time_t+40, then the min watermark across all partitions will be time_t+40, less 10s for out-of-order to emit time_t+30 watermark, hence making all events between time_t to time_t+30 late arriving.

Comment: I think you meant to say time_t+40 less 30s for out-of-order, so the watermark is at time_t+10 -- but that doesn't change your argument. However, events between time_t and time_t+10 will only be late if they follow the watermark -- and there's no reason to think they will.

Comment: If the 30s out-of-orderness estimate is correct for each partition, then with per-partition watermarking, nothing will be late. And yes, setting the WS on the KafkaSource is sufficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257276/discussion-between-dan-and-david-anderson).